# Shared availability rules schema design

Tags: mysql, database-design, schema

I'm designing a schema which includes the concept of availability rules. The rules are periods of a day when a linked entity is available. This can be the opening hours of a business, the working hours of a staff member, or the availability hours of a specific service. This schema needs to allow for multiple periods on the same day. The rules aren't shared across entities, a business has one group of rules, and each of the other entities are the same.

My first run through this, gave me this schema, but the fact that `availabilityGroup` doesn't actually contain any data makes me feel like this could be done differently.

```sql
CREATE TABLE `business` (
  `id` integer PRIMARY KEY,
  `name` varchar(255),
  `availabilityId` integer,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_business_to_availability_group` FOREIGN KEY (`availabilityId`) REFERENCES `availabilityGroup` (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `staff` (
  `id` integer PRIMARY KEY,
  `availabilityId` integer,
  `name` varchar(255),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_staff_to_availability_group` FOREIGN KEY (`availabilityId`) REFERENCES `availabilityGroup` (`id`)
);


CREATE TABLE `service` (
  `id` integer PRIMARY KEY,
  `availabilityId` integer,
  `name` varchar(255),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_service_to_availability_group` FOREIGN KEY (`availabilityId`) REFERENCES `availabilityGroup` (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `availabilityGroup` (
  `id` integer PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE `availabilityRule` (
  `id` integer PRIMARY KEY,
  `availabilityGroupId` integer,
  `day` string,
  `startTime` time,
  `endTime` time,
    CONSTRAINT `FK_availability_rule_to_availability_group` FOREIGN KEY (`availabilityGroupId`) REFERENCES `availabilityGroup` (`id`)
);
```

Another possible solution could be to make use of single table inheritance with something like this, which is supported by the ORM we're using too https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance

```sql
CREATE TABLE `singleAvailabilityRulesTable` (
  `id` integer PRIMARY KEY,
  `discriminator` enum('business','staff','service'),
  `entityId` integer,
  `day` string,
  `startTime` time,
  `endTime` time
);
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you tracking availability by generic day of week, a specific date, or both?

Comment: Generic day of week

Answer (score 0):

It's not worth trying to cram everything into one generic table.  Better to just build off each entity like so:

```
CREATE TABLE business
(
  business_id  INT           NOT NULL
 ,name         VARCHAR(255)  NOT NULL
 ,CONSTRAINT PK_business PRIMARY KEY (business_id)
 ,CONSTRAINT AK_business UNIQUE (name)
)
;

CREATE TABLE business_hours_of_operation
(
  business_id  INT              NOT NULL
 ,day_of_week  TINYINT          NOT NULL
 ,start_hour   DECIMAL(4,2)     NOT NULL /* Expressed as fractional - i.e. 12:30 = 12.5 */
 ,hours_open   DECIMAL(5,2)     NOT NULL
 ,CONSTRAINT FK_Hours_Of_Operation_For_Business FOREIGN KEY (business_id) REFERENCES business (business_id)
 ,CONSTRAINT PK_Business_Hours_Of_Operation PRIMARY KEY (business_id, day_of_week, start_hour)
 ,CONSTRAINT CK_Business_Hours_Of_Operation_Day_Of_Week_Is_Valid CHECK(day_of_week >= 1 AND day_of_week <= 7)
 ,CONSTRAINT CK_Business_Hours_Of_Operation_Start_Hour_Is_Valid CHECK(start_hour >= 0.00 AND start_hour < 24.00)
 ,CONSTRAINT CK_Business_Hours_Of_Operation_Hours_Open_Is_Valid CHECK(hours_open > 0.00 AND hours_open <= 168.00)
)
;
```

To display everything in intervals:

```
SELECT
  business_id
 ,day_of_week AS start_day_of_week
 ,hour AS start_hour
 ,1 + MOD(day_of_week - 1 + FLOOR((hour + hours_open)/24),7) AS end_day_of_week
 ,MOD(hour + hours_open,24) AS end_hour
FROM
  business_hours_of_operation
;
```

You'll need to lock things down with stored procedures and/or triggers to ensure that the intervals don't overlap and any other business rules.

See Fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=988d11efa9f748286afec48aabcdca8d).